# openCV: is it possible to time cvQueryFrame to synchronize with a projector?

Tags: opencv, camera, synchronization, projector

When I capture camera images of projected patterns using openCV via 'cvQueryFrame', I often end up with an unintended artifact:  the projector's scan line.  That is, since I'm unable to precisely time when 'cvQueryFrame' captures an image, the image taken does not respect the constant 30Hz refresh of the projector.  The result is that typical horizontal band familiar to those who have turned a video camera onto a TV screen.

Short of resorting to hardware sync, has anyone had some success with approximate (e.g., 'good enough') informal projector-camera sync in openCV?

Below are two solutions I'm considering, but was hoping this is a common enough problem that an elegant solution might exist.  My less-than-elegant thoughts are:

- Add a slider control in the cvWindow displaying the video for the user to control a timing offset from 0 to 1/30th second, then set up a queue timer at this interval.  Whenever a frame is needed, rather than calling 'cvQueryFrame' directly, I would request a callback to execute 'cvQueryFrame' at the next firing of the timer.  In this way, theoretically the user would be able to use the slider to reduce the scan line artifact, provided that the timer resolution is sufficient.
- After receiving a frame via 'cvQueryFrame', examine the frame for the tell-tale horizontal band by looking for a delta in HSV values for a vertical column of pixels.  Naturally this would only work when the subject being photographed contains a fiducial strip of uniform color under smoothly varying lighting.

I've used several cameras with OpenCV, most recently a Canon SLR (7D).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your proposed solution will work. cvQueryFrame basically copies the next available frame from the camera driver's buffer (or advances a pointer in a memory mapped region, or *blah* according to your driver implementation).

In any case, the timing of the cvQueryFrame call has no effect on when the image was captured.

So as you suggested, hardware sync is really the only route, unless you have a special camera, like a point grey camera, which gives you explicit software control of the frame integration start trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has nothing to do with synchronizing but, have you tried extending the exposure time? Or doing so by intentionally "blending" two or more images into one?